# Trying to print chosen element from associative array from the datalist

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form and I am trying to print the chosen element from the array to print the description of the course. This is a part of my code. The rest of the code works fine. I only have a problem with the array. I am using method and action. I feel like my foreach statement is faulty however I couldn't figure it out. Any idea what's causing the printing of all the array elements?

```
    <label for="course">Choose a course:</label>
    <input list="courseOptions" id="course" name="course">
    <datalist id="courseOptions">
        <option value="COMP1230">
        <option value="COMP2129">
        <option value="COMP2147">
        <option value="COMP2130">
        <option value="COMP2138">
        <option value="GSSC1054">    
    </datalist>
<?php
    $course = array("COMP1230"=>"Advanced Web Development",
    "COMP2129"=>"Advanced Object-Oriented Programming",
    "COMP2147"=>"System Analysis, Design & Testing",
    "COMP2130"=>"Application Development Using Java",
    "COMP2138"=>"Advanced Database Development",
    "GSSC1054"=>"Forensic Psychology"
    );
    
    foreach($course as $courseCode => $courseName){
        echo("<div> Course Name:   $courseName </div>");
    } 
?>
```

I only want the chosen option to be printed

[image: I only want the chosen option to be printed]

Comment: Well, first you'd need to submit the selection (via a form or AJAX) before PHP can do anything with it

Comment: Yeah. I've done that

Comment: Ok well there was no evidence of that in the question - no `<form>` tag, no attempt to check the `$_POST` data to find what was submitted. Have you studied a HTML/PHP forms tutorial at all? Because you would have seen the use of `$_POST`.

Comment: _"Any idea what's causing the printing of all the array elements?"_ - uhm, the fact that you wrote code to do exactly that ...?

Answer (score 1):

When the form is submitted, use `$_POST['course']` to get the chosen course.

```
if (isset($_POST['course']) {
    echo "<div>Course Name: {$course[$_POST['course']]}</div>";
} else {
    foreach($course as $courseCode => $courseName){
        echo("<div> Course Name:   $courseName </div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked thank you so much.